# Python: Incident causing wrong result?

Tags: python, python-2.7

The following code is expected to return 'none', however, it seems I've done something wrong with the incident:

```
def function_that_prints():
    print "I printed"
    f1 = function_that_prints()
    print f1
```

I've tried putting the 3rd line left aligned but it's still not happening. Please correct me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With the third line indented so that it is part of your function, `function_that_prints()` recurses (it calls itself) indefinitely and python will raise a RuntimeError complaining that the maximum recursion depth has been exceeded.

If you do not indent the third line you have the following code snippet:

```
def function_that_prints():
    print "I printed"
f1 = function_that_prints() 
print f1

# Running this will produce:
# I printed
# None
```

The statement `f1 = function_that_prints()` will print "I printed" and then set `f1` to `None`, as you suggested.

Then the statement `print f1` will print the value of `f1`, which is `None`.